# Why won't my point in Species class point to its heterogeneous class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

My code consists of a class animal and 2 sub classes inheriting animal charactistics - amphibian, and fish. The code compiles but the oorder of the deconstructors kills them from bottom to top but i want them to be killed from top to bottom as the display function order suggests-
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Animal{
public:
    Animal(string name, string diet, bool queue)
        : name_species(name), regime(diet), queue(queue){
            if(name == ""){cout << "Error, name can't be empty!" << endl; }
            else { cout << "A new animal" << endl; }}
    virtual ~Animal(){ cout << "End of animal" << endl; }
    virtual void display()const;
protected:
    string name_species;
    string regime;
    bool queue;
};

void Animal::display() const{
    cout << "I present the species " << name_species << endl;
}

class Fish : public Animal {
public:
    Fish(string name, unsigned int scales, string diet = "Carnivore", bool  queue = true)
        : Animal(name, diet, queue), scales(scales){ cout << "Add a fish" << endl; }
    ~Fish(){ cout << "Fish species " << name_species << " is turned off. " << endl; }
    void display() const override;
private:
    unsigned int scales;
};
void Fish::display() const {
    Animal::display();
    if(queue == true){cout << "I have a tail "; }
    else { cout << "I don't have a tail "; } cout << "and i follow " << regime <<    endl;
    cout << "I have " << scales << " scales" << endl;
}


class Amphibian : public Animal {
public: Amphibian(string name, string diet, unsigned int claws = 4, bool queue = false)
        : Animal(name, diet, queue), claws(claws){ cout << "Add an amphibian" << endl; }
        void affiche() const;
        ~Amphibian(){ cout << "Amphibian species " << name_species << " is turned off. " << endl; }
private:
        unsigned int claws;
};

void Amphibian::display() const {
    Animal::display();
    if(queue == true){ cout << "I have a tail "; }
    else { cout << "I don't have a tail " ; } cout << "and i follow " << regime << endl;
    cout << "I have " << scales << " scales " << endl;
}

class Species {
public:
    virtual void display()const = 0;
    virtual ~Species();
private:
    vector<Animal*> animals;
};

void Species::display()const{
    for(size_t i(0); i < animals.size(); ++i){
        animals[i]->display(); }
}

Species::~Species(){
    for(size_t i(0); i < animals.size(); ++i){
        delete animals[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    Amphibian kermit("lizard", "insects");
    Fish nemo("dolphin", 6);
    Fish sala("salamander", 4);

    Animal* animal(&kermit);
    animal->display();

    animal = &nemo;
    animal->display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be coding as if `Fish` and `Amphibian` are subclasses of `Species`.  Your code says they are not.  Perhaps the nature of the English word "species" makes it unclear whether it's a *container of things* or a *particular thing*,

Answer (score 0):

The following code suggests that you see `Species` as something more general than `Animal`:

```
 Species* animal(&kermit);
 animal->display();
 animal = &nemo;
```

In this case you shall make sure the inheritance is declared, by changing the class definition to :

```
class Animal : Species {
...
};
```

Some remarks nevertheless:

- as all species have a name, whether vegetal or animal,  you could consider to move member `Animal::name_species` to class `Species`;
- the fact that the name of the class `Species` is in plural, that you have a   vector as member, and that every element of this member is displayed or deleted when the corresponding operation is called for the member tends however to suggest that Species is an aggregation of `Animals`.  It is then not clear how you add elements to your vector.
- Rather than using raw pointers in the aggregation, you could use shared_ptr instead.  You then don't need to delete the aniamls yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing inherits from class `Species` so conversion not possible using assignment technique.

There are no methods in `Species` to **convert** an `Animal` into a `Species`, so no luck there.  Compiler running out of ideas on how to convert `Animal` to `Species`.

Looks like `Species` is a **container** of `Animal`s.  You will need to supply a method that adds an `Animal` to the container inside `Species` or make the container public.

You want something like this:

```
Species s;
s.animals.push_back(&kermit);
```